# Looking for an expression similar to 'resort to doing something' but without a negative connotation

Tags: word-choice, verbs

From Cambridge Dictionary the definition of 'resort to' is:

**to do something that you do not want to do because you cannot find any other way of achieving something**

*I had to resort to violence/threats to get my money.*

I am looking for a similar expression, but without the idea of being forced to a certain path by the circumstances.
The idea I want to express is:

*After a careful examination, we ??? to the new technique*

What expression can I use? Is *turn to* correct?

Comment: _ended up with_? As in _we ended up with using the new technique._

Comment: We decided to use  the new technique!

Comment: ... finally decided on ...

Comment: "elected to" might also work. "After careful examination, we elected to _use the new technique_."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **adopt** *verb*
>   2 Choose to take up or follow (an idea, method, or course of action)
>   ‘this approach has been adopted by many big banks’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adopt)

Your sample sentence would look like this:

- After a careful examination, we adopted the new technique.

Answer (score 0):

**take a new turn** [for something] [TFD][1](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+new+turn)

> to begin a new course or direction.

As in:

> After a careful examination, we took a new turn to the technique

.